# b2c msal User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter

Tags: typescript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

When I log in via `loginRedirect` I can see the MSAL token is populated on the redirect, but when attempting to use the token I get this error:

> Could not silently retrieve token from storage.
>
> AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'" directly after a successful login via Angular SPA app connected to Azure B2C.

I found something similar in a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/214#issuecomment-375142944), and then commented on [another issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/94#issuecomment-375161356) after when an error appeared after being forced to do the `tokenPopup()` as the result of no token:

> "This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation"

They're likely not related but they are both blocking me

In this code, `loginredirect` works and I can see the token in local storage, then the next time the token is used I receive console log `authCallback-err` then log the "Could not silently retrieve token from storage..." and error first mentioned.

```
@Injectable()
export class MsalService {
  private access_token: string;

  private tenantConfig = {
    tenant: environment.tenant,
    clientID: environment.clientID,
    signUpSignInPolicy: environment.signUpSignInPolicy,
    b2cScopes: environment.b2cScopes
  };

  private authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/" +
    this.tenantConfig.tenant +
    "/" +
    this.tenantConfig.signUpSignInPolicy;

  private clientApplication: Msal.UserAgentApplication;

  private authCallback(errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
    var _this = this;
    console.log("authCallback");
    // For loginRedirect, tokenType = "id_token". For acquireTokenRedirect, tokenType:"access_token".
    if (token) {
      console.log("authCallback- Id token", token);
      this.access_token = token;
    } else {
      console.log("authCallback-err : " + error + ":" + errorDesc);
      alert("error here");
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    this.clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
      this.tenantConfig.clientID,
      this.authority,
      this.authCallback,
      {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:4200/msallogin"
      }
    );
  }

  get authenticated() {
    const user = this.clientApplication.getUser();
    if (user) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public loginRedirect(): void {
    this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
  }

  public getAuthenticationToken(): Promise<string> {
    return this.clientApplication
      .acquireTokenSilent(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
      .then(token => {
        console.log("Got silent access token: ", token);
        return token;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Could not silently retrieve token from storage.", error);
        return this.clientApplication
          .acquireTokenPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
          .then(token => {
            console.log("Got popup access token: ", token);
            return token;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log("Could not retrieve token from popup.", error);
            this.clientApplication.acquireTokenRedirect(
              this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes
            );
            return Promise.resolve("");
          });
      });
  }

  public login(): void {
    var _this = this;
    this.clientApplication.loginPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
      function(idToken: any) {
        _this.clientApplication
          .acquireTokenSilent(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
          .then(
            function(accessToken: any) {
              _this.access_token = accessToken;
              console.log("ACCESS TOKEN: \n " + _this.access_token);
            },
            function(error: any) {
              _this.clientApplication
                .acquireTokenPopup(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes)
                .then(
                  function(accessToken: any) {
                    _this.access_token = accessToken;
                  },
                  function(error: any) {
                    alert("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                  }
                );
            }
          );
      },
      function(error: any) {
        alert("Error during login:\n" + error);
      }
    );
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.clientApplication.logout();
  }

  isOnline(): boolean {
    return this.clientApplication.getUser() != null;
  }

  public getUser(): string {
    const user = this.clientApplication.getUser();
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }

    return user.name;
  }
}
```

Then, once I've logged in, the redirect comes back and I redirect to another route in angular. That component has an MSAL service injected.

At that point, I call `getUser()` and can see my username. I then click a button to issue a web request, issuing the next piece of code as an interceptor, but fails as there is no token

@Injectable()
export class MSALAuthenticationHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private msalService: MsalService) {}

```
  @intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(
      this.msalService.getAuthenticationToken()
    ).switchMap(token => {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(req);
    });
  }
}
```

My B2C works as a postman app connecting to an Azure Function, it's definitely either B2C config, my code or MSAL. [If it is](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/214#issuecomment-372307664) I cannot modify those settings from the B2C Policy blade so unsure how he resolved it.

The B2c config is listed in the comment in [1](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/94#issuecomment-375161356)
I've spent a lot of time on this, and it may be easy, but with multiple scopes across various apps and the different issues and changes to the scope blade it seems tougher than it should be

Using:

```
Angular: "5.2.0"
MSAL: "^0.1.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

What I did is adding 2 lines to the XML file of the sign-in policy and that solved my problem.

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>

<SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>

<SessionExpiryInSeconds>86400</SessionExpiryInSeconds>

</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

I hope it will help. :)